# URI Routing using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone help me?

I am new in codeigniter and currently working in a project.

I have a controller named Articles with the following methods:

```
index()

page($page)

category($category)

view($slug)
```

I want to change my urls as follow:

from `http://site.ph/articles/page/<page>` to `http://site.ph/articles/<page>`

`http://site.ph/articles/category/<category>/<page>` to `http://site.ph/articles/<category>/<page>`

and

`http://site.ph/articles/view/<slug>` to `http://site.ph/articles/<category>/<slug>`

Thanks!

Comment: application->config->routes.php. You can change routes there. CHeck the documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use URI Routing for this pourpose...

U need to go to the `application/config/routes.php` file and add the following array's in the file

```
$route["articles/$page"] = "articles/page/$1";
$route["articles/$category/$page"] = "articles/category/$1/$2";
$route["articles/view/harold-paola"] = "articles/$1/$2";
```

for more details on uri routing check this link 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: thanks! it helps. i used this codes `$route["articles"] = "articles/page/1";
$route["articles/(:num)"] = "articles/page/$1";
$route["articles/(:any)/(:num)"] = "articles/category/$1/$2";
$route["articles/(:any)/(:any)"] = "articles/view/$1/$2";`

Comment: follow-up question:

I add $page variable in category method `category($category,$page)`

it works when i browse 

`http://site.ph/articles/category/<category>/1`

but it displays page not found when i browse

`http://site.ph/articles/category/<category>`

this is my working route config

`$route["articles"] = "articles/page/1";
$route["articles/(:num)"] = "articles/page/$1";
$route["articles/(:any)/(:num)"] = "articles/category/$1/$2";
$route["articles/(:any)/(:any)"] = "articles/view/$1/$2";`